# can't rename existing file with python

Tags: python-3.x

I'am trying to rename files with their ID extract from files, sometimes i have duplicate files with  differents names , when i'am trying to rename it with it's ID ,"Impossible ranaming existing files" .
here is an exemple:
input:

- 0000307187.CNF
- 0000307188.CNF
- 0000307189.CNF

they have all the Same ID

Output:

- G21SNE44-748S2
- G21SNE44-748S2_1
- G21SNE44-748S2_2

I have hundred of files updated daily.so i have to keep old files (named before)
and renameing new files daily.
here is my code:

```py
import sys
import numpy as np
import time
import struct
import os

def uint8_at(f, pos):
    f.seek(pos)
    return np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.dtype('<u1'), count=1)[0]


def uint16_at(f, pos):
    f.seek(pos)
    return np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.dtype('<u2'), count=1)[0]


def uint32_at(f, pos):
    f.seek(pos)
    return np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.dtype('<u4'), count=1)[0]


def uint64_at(f, pos):
    f.seek(pos)
    return np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.dtype('<u8'), count=1)[0]



def string_at(f, pos, length):
    f.seek(pos)
    # In order to avoid characters with not utf8 encoding
    return f.read(length).decode(errors='replace').rstrip('\00').rstrip()

###########################################################
# Definitions for locating and reading data inside the file
###########################################################


def get_strings(f, offs_str):
    """Read strings section."""

    sample_name = string_at(f, offs_str + 0x0030, 0x40)
    sample_id = string_at(f, offs_str + 0x0070, 0x10)
  

    out_dic = {
               'Sample name': sample_name,
               'Sample id': sample_id,

              }

    return out_dic


def read_cnf_file(filename, write_output=False):

    # Dictionary with all the information read
    read_dic = {}
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        i = 0
        while True:
            # List of available section headers
            sec_header = 0x70 + i*0x30
            i += 1
            # Section id in header
            sec_id_header = uint32_at(f, sec_header)

            # End of section list
            if sec_id_header == 0x00:
                break

            # Location of the begining of each sections
            sec_loc = uint32_at(f, sec_header+0x0a)
            # Known section id's:
            # Parameter section (times, energy calibration, etc)
  
            # String section
            if sec_id_header == 0x00012001:
                offs_str = sec_loc
                read_dic.update(get_strings(f, offs_str))

         

            # For known sections: section header ir repeated in section block
            '''if (sec_id_header != uint32_at(f, sec_loc)):
                print('File {}: Format error\n'.format(filename))'''

    # Once the file is read, some derived magnitudes can be obtained
    return read_dic
```

Here the updated code:

```py
from pathlib import Path 
from tkinter import filedialog

dirname=filedialog.askdirectory()
work_dir = Path(dirname)
paths = work_dir.glob('**/*.CNF')
for file in paths:

    c = read_cnf_file(file, 'TRUE')
    new_stem = c['Sample id']
    rename_matches = len(list(work_dir.glob('**/' + new_stem + '*.CNF')))
    if rename_matches:
        new_name = new_stem + '_' + str(rename_matches)+'.CNF'
    else:
        new_name = new_stem + '.CNF'
    file.rename(file.parent / new_name)
```

I'am using jupyter notebook , i get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileExistsError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-f34284fc5490> in <module>
     13     else:
     14         new_name = new_stem + '.CNF'
---> 15     file.rename(file.parent / new_name)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py in rename(self, target)
   1356         if self._closed:
   1357             self._raise_closed()
-> 1358         self._accessor.rename(self, target)
   1359         return self.__class__(target)
   1360 

FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Impossible de créer un fichier déjà existant: 'J:\\APEX\\Data_files\\0000307072.CNF' -> 'J:\\APEX\\Data_files\\G21SNO48-879E1_1.CNF'
```

when i run

```
dir ('J:/APEX/Data_files/G21SNO48-879E1*.*')
```

I get

```
['__add__',
 '__class__',
 '__contains__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__',
 '__getnewargs__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__iter__',
 '__le__',
 '__len__',
 '__lt__',
 '__mod__',
 '__mul__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__rmod__',
 '__rmul__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 'capitalize',
 'casefold',
 'center',
 'count',
 'encode',
 'endswith',
 'expandtabs',
 'find',
 'format',
 'format_map',
 'index',
 'isalnum',
 'isalpha',
 'isascii',
 'isdecimal',
 'isdigit',
 'isidentifier',
 'islower',
 'isnumeric',
 'isprintable',
 'isspace',
 'istitle',
 'isupper',
 'join',
 'ljust',
 'lower',
 'lstrip',
 'maketrans',
 'partition',
 'replace',
 'rfind',
 'rindex',
 'rjust',
 'rpartition',
 'rsplit',
 'rstrip',
 'split',
 'splitlines',
 'startswith',
 'strip',
 'swapcase',
 'title',
 'translate',
 'upper',
 'zfill']
```

Comment: Please share more details about the read_cnf_file function.

Comment: this function read CNF file and  exctract the ID :'Sample id'

Comment: Okay, can you add that function as well? So that anyone can try to replicate the issue easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to enumerate the list of matching files you'll iterate over. What you need to do in this case is to check for the existence of previously renamed files that match your current renaming pattern in order to properly rename the current file in every iteration. Like this:

```
from pathlib import Path 
from tkinter import filedialog
import shutil
dirname=filedialog.askdirectory()

work_dir = Path(dirname)
paths = work_dir.glob('**/*.CNF')
for file in paths:
    c = read_cnf_file(path, 'TRUE')
    new_stem = c['Sample id']
    rename_matches = len(list(work_dir.glob('**/' + new_stem + '*.CNF')))
    if rename_matches:
        new_name = new_stem + '_' + str(rename_matches) + '.CNF'
    else:
        new_name = new_stem + '.CNF'
    file.rename(file.parent / new_name)
```

As you can see, I isolate the new string that will be used to rename the file (`new_stem`) so that I can use it to search files, that have already been renamed, that contain said string in their names.

The number of matching files is stored in `rename_matches` and, coincidentally, this number matches the next number to be used when renaming a file that shared the `new_stem`. For instance, if the files `G21SNE44-748S2.CNF` and `G21SNE44-748S2_1.CNF` already exist (were just renamed in previous iterations), `rename_matches` will be `2`, and the new name will be `'G21SNE44-748S2' + '_' + str(rename_matches) + '.CNF'`... `G21SNE44-748S2_2.CNF`.

Finally, we simply rename the file to either new name we get based on the previous logic. Note I added `file.parent` in the `rename()` method; this is because I noted you're making a recursive search of files to rename, so I assume you have files in sub-directories as well. If we don't add this when renaming, files in sub-directories will be renamed AND moved to the working directory (the directory provided in the dialog).

Comment: That doesn't work if the number of exist file > rename_matches, when i have a lot of exist files

Comment: @YoussefMhamdi, could you rephrase, please? What is "number of exist file?"

Comment: the file is duplicated more than ten times , i get this error:  FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Could not create an already existing file: 'J:\\APEX\\Data_files\\0000307072.CNF' -> 'J:\\APEX\\Data_files\\G21SNO48-879E1_1.CNF'

Comment: @YoussefMhamdi, can you share the exact new code you have right after the imports?. Add it to your publications.

Comment: I updated the code ,

Comment: @YoussefMhamdi, I ran a mockup example on my computer and it worked just fine. You're gonna have to share how you're runnig the script and the exact output you're getting.

Comment: i get this error     FileExistsError      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 1358, in rename
    self._accessor.rename(self, target)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Impossible de créer un fichier déjà existant: 'J:\\APEX\\Data_files\\0000307072.CNF' -> 'J:\\APEX\\Data_files\\G21SNO48-879E1_1.CNF'

Comment: @YoussefMhamdi, copy/paste the exact command you execute (along with the command prompt) and output to the post.
Also, list the directory for that file, like this: `dir J:\APEX\Data_files\G21SNO48-879E1*.*`

Comment: ,I'am using jupyterlab notebook,i tryed with this command prompt : python file.py , i get the same error.

Comment: Get the directory listing: `dir J:\APEX\Data_files\G21SNO48-879E1*.*`.

Comment: Get the directory listing: dir J:\APEX\Data_files\G21SNO48-879E1*.*:   Done

Comment: You get the directory listing from your Windows command prompt, not from Python's `dir()` function.